# Flask & WTForms: DatePicker Widget to display a date

Tags: python, flask, datepicker, jinja2, datefield

I have a small Flask app which has three fields (Destination, Start Time and End Time). I'd like to use DatePicker widget to display the calender when selecting start and end dates.

With my current scripts the date widget doesn't spawn at all. What am I missing here?

`app.py:`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import SubmitField, SelectField, DateField
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask.ext.admin.form.widgets import DatePickerWidget

class GeneralForm(Form):
    destination = SelectField(choices = data)
    start_time = DateField('Start at', widget=DatePickerWidget())
    end_time = DateField('End at', widget=DatePickerWidget())
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = GeneralForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        destination = form.destination.data
        start_time = form.start_time.data
        end_time = form.end_time.data
        return render_template('page.html', form=form)
    else:
        return render_template('index.html', form=form)

bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`index.html:`

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="{{url_for('.static', filename='mystyle.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="{{url_for('.static', filename='datepicker.css')}}">
<link rel="javascript"
      href="{{url_for('.static', filename='main.js')}}">
<link rel="javascript"
      href="{{url_for('.static', filename='bootstrap-datepicker.js')}}"

<form action="#" method="post">
     {{ form.destination }}
     {{ form.start_time(class='datepicker') }}
     {{ form.end_time(class='datepicker') }}
     {{ form.submit }}
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Flask-Admin's `DatePickerWidget()` basically adds `data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" data-role="datepicker"` attributes to an input field. After that a custom JavaScript function located in [`flask_admin/static/admin/js/form.js`](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/static/admin/js/form.js) activates the Bootstrap-Datepicker widget on these fields.

So you need to include this script in your template (or write your own).
Add this line at the top of your template, which includes a helper macro:

```
{% import 'admin/static.html' as admin_static with context %}
```

and then you can include the `form.js` via adding these lines into your template (this script requires `moment.js` as well):

```
<script src="{{ admin_static.url(filename='vendor/moment.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ admin_static.url(filename='admin/js/form.js') }}"></script>
```

*Note:* You can also use the Bootstrap-Datepicker js and css files shipped with Flask-Admin. See the `form_css()` and `form_js()` macros in [`flask_admin/templates/bootstrap3/admin/lib.html`](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/templates/bootstrap3/admin/lib.html) and copy the corresponding lines into your template.

Comment: The app is not able to find the template admin/static.html. The import line throws TemplateNotFound error.

Comment: Infact I have added form.js and moment.js from github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/tree/master/flask_admin/static/admin/. The widget still doesn't spawn.

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared the flask-bootstrap base.html reference file at the top of your page?

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" as wtf %}
```

You can then initiate your form in your page by simply adding in the following

```
{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
```

Comment: Yes, and actually I have tried {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}. However I'm still  not able to get the datepicker widget working. Thanks for your response!